# How to accept trusted certificate added to iOS device via iPhone Configuration Utility in application

Tags: ios, ssl, ios6, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I want my application to have the ability to accept trusted root certificates that have been added to an iOS device by using the iPhone Configuration Utility.

I added a trusted certificate to an iOS device using the iPhone Configuration Utility and confirmed that Safari accepts my self-signed certificate by sending my server a https request. However, when I make a simple test app that uses NSURLConnection to make a GET request to my server using HTTPS, I get the following error message:

"
Error - The certificate for this server is invalid.  You might be connecting to a server enter code here`that is pretending to be “myserver” which could put your confidential information at risk. 
"

I imagine that my iOS app is sandboxed, and does not accept the self-signed certificate by default. I've tried manipulating code in willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge to accept the self signed certificate without success. I was hoping that someone else has figured out how to do this. I do not want to accept all self-signed certificates. I only want to accept self-signed certificates that have been configured to be trusted on the device.